# how to convert to uppcase all the elements in a vector in C++

Tags: c++11, vector, cout

I want to display all the elements in a vector. My code displays all elements but converts to uppercase just the last one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string words;
    string it;
    vector<string>list_words;

    while (cin>>words)
        list_words.push_back(words);
            for (auto it = words.begin(); it != words.end() && !isspace(*it); ++it)
                *it = toupper(*it);
                cout<<list_words.size()<<endl;
                cout<<words<<endl;
                



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code indentation doesn't correspond to what it actually does. That suggests that you copy-pasted the code with no idea of your own and, hence, you won't be able to appreciate the answers. No offence, but read your C++ textbook, there is no other way.

Comment: I did not copy paste. I am sorry. Sure, I am a beginner.

Comment: "My code displays all elements" No [it does not](https://godbolt.org/z/r4fzs5). It only displays the last word. Note how it populates `list_words`, but never actually accesses its elements, only its size.

Comment: Thanks Igor! I have found the solution on my own after reading one more time the book instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I checked again how to index each "word".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    char index;
    vector<string>g_words;
        while (cin>> word)
            g_words.push_back(word);
                for (auto &word : g_words)
                    for (decltype (word.size()) index = 0;
                        index != word.size() && !isspace(word[index]); ++index)
                            word[index] = toupper(word[index]);
                                for ( auto word : g_words)
                                    cout<<word<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```